# Extjs- Fire the handler of an action column in grid

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, sencha-architect

I have defined a grid and i have an action element in every row of the grid to delete that row. Is there a way to fire the handler of that action element in first row without clicking from UI.

```
{
 xtype: 'actioncolumn',
 text: "Delete Me,
 items: [{ 
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
    tooltip: "Delete",
    handler: 'deleteGridRec',
  }} 
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `action column` sample code

Comment: {
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    text: "Delete Me",
                    items: [{
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
                        tooltip: "Delete"
                        handler: 'deleteGridRec',
                    }
                }

Comment: Why do you want to achieve row click without actually clicking on it ?

Comment: @Tejas , That is a backend operation without user intervention

Comment: why you even need that, if you need to delete first row at any point you can directly delete that from the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `colIdx` is the index of your `action column` and `grid` is the grid contain this column. Then below code to fire the handler of that action element in first row.

```
deleteGridRec(grid,0,colIdx);
```

or use

```
actionColumn.items[0].handler(grid.up('grid'),0,colIdx);
```

where `actionColumn` variable contains `action column` for row deletion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 2 doubts:-   1. My definition for deleteGridRec is `deleteGridRec: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row)` . What should i add for remaining params         2. How should i declare actionColumn

Comment: Which version of extjs currently using?

Comment: Version 6.2.1 is what am using

Comment: 1. In extjs 6.2.1 `action column handler` you only need to pass 3 parameters

Comment: 2. You can get the action column component by `Ext.getCmp` by id or query (selector, [root] )  by other params

Comment: the action column is present in every row of the grid, so the Id  is not constant

Comment: In my understanding only one id is assigned for an actioncolumn and its instance are created for seperated rows. So there is no id conflict issues.

Comment: Thanks for your time .Please guide me how to assign actionColumn

Comment: `{
 xtype: 'actioncolumn',
 text: "Delete Me",
id:'actionColumn',
 items: [{ 
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
    tooltip: "Delete",
    handler: 'deleteGridRec',
  }} 
}`

and `actionColumn = Ext.getCmp('actionColumn');`

Comment: or use `actionColumn = grid.query('[text="Delete Me"]')[0]`